# access cookie in content script in google chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have simple extension in Google chrome. The content script is a js file with a simple alert statement. Now I want to get the value of cookie by name 'sid'. If i use $.cookie('sid'), it's just not working. I am not sure how to use the chrome.cookie to get this working.

All I want to do is store the value of a cookie in a variable.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use this `$.cookie("example")` you need to include the plugin file you can get [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

which is `<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>`